# Hiding the lupe icon of a NSSearchField

Tags: swift, nstextfield, nsimage, nscell, nssearchfield

I’m using a `NSSearchField` (not subclassed). When it’s not focused, the `placeholderString` is centered. But the lupe icon on the left appears a bit offset, so in fact the whole thing appears not to be centered.

**Is it possible to hide the lupe icon?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not any direct access to the icon, so that a workaround is first access to the NSSearchField cell (casted as shown), and afterwards access to its button cell.

self in this example is an instance of NSSearchField

```
[(NSButtonCell *)[(NSSearchFieldCell *)self.cell searchButtonCell] setTransparent:YES];
```

Deafault Search Field:

[image]

Hidden/Transparent Icon:

[image]

Comment: It may be better to add some description to your answer, to help others understand it.

Comment: I agree @MartinZhai. Hope the edited version clarifies it.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! Works really great. However, I couldn’t find out how to hide the icon when the searchField is inactive but display it when the user is editing it. Any easy solution for that too? :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift3 conversion:

```
(self.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).searchButtonCell?.isTransparent = true
```