# NSSearchField: How to hide icon and border?

Tags: swift, cocoa, drawing, subclass, nssearchfield

This is kind of a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482902/nssearchfield-how-to-hide-the-icon-lupe) question. Because everything I know about Swift is Swift3, I`m wondering if someone could "translate" the suggested solution in this answer.

Also:

I made a NSSearchfield without border, put it in a framed view, and it still shows the gray border. I would be curious of how to disable the animated gray border and maybe even how to change the color of the gray "search" line.

My ugly result now looks like this:

[image]

It would be a big help if someone could tell me how to manage this difficult NSSearchfield.

//UPDATE

According to firstinq´s answer, the icon now disappeared, which is great. But still, there is this disturbing animated gray border. Which I can´t understand: The NSSearchFielt is inside a NSView (blue border). So everything outside the NSView should be hidden, right?. So why am I still seeing the gray border? `cell.isBordered = false`has no effect.
Any advice how to handle that?

[image]

This is how I draw the border of the NSView:

```
class SearchFieldBorder: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        self.layer?.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the icon: cast the cell to NSSearchFieldCell and set the cell's searchButtonCell to transparent. Possible swift3 version:

```
if let cell = self.searchField.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell {
    cell.searchButtonCell?.isTransparent = true
}
```

Here searchField is an NSSearchField

To remove the focus border:

```
searchField.focusRingType = .none
```

To change grey line/cursor it would be better to subclass the NSSearchField and override the methods.
You can get an idea from [here](https://github.com/dautermann/ChangeCursorColor/blob/master/ChangeCursorColor/CCTextField.swift).

Comment: This is definitely a progress. Thank you for the "translation"!.

Comment: You are welcome. How did you create the bordered NSView. Can you post some code? Is it transparent by any chance?

Comment: @JoschHazard, I have updated the answer with a possible solution to remove the focus border. Can you try it?

Comment: I just posted the code. The NSView itself of course is transparent. But I don´t think the border is.

Comment: This is just awesome. `FocusRingType`, how did you find that? Thank you anyway.

Comment: It took a while to go though the properties. Have not done any cocoa/mac development in ages :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll supplement the answer above.
To hide the search icon, assign a nil to the SearchButtonCell property

```
if let cell = searchField.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell {
      cell.searchButtonCell = nil
}
```